# unterminated string literal / Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting...

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

...in **Firefox** and...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

...in **Chrome** when I run...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function addJSBeforeEndBody(code) {
       $('body').append('<script>' + code + '</script>');
  }
  addJSBeforeEndBody('$(document).ready(function() { console.log("I never end up here."); });');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing paren to your append() call.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/05/617901.aspx

Comment: I have `);` at the end of append()...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Break up the string `"</script>"` (in the javascript code); it will be interpreted as an actual closing script tag rather than the string literal you intend.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function addJSBeforeEndBody(code) {
       $('body').append('<script>' + code + '</scr' + 'ipt>');
  }
  addJSBeforeEndBody('$(document).ready(function() { console.log("It works now."); });');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, I remember that issue. Good call!

Comment: Yes it's in html file. What do you mean by break up the word "script"?

Comment: @Erik I mean exactly that; you can't have a literal `"</script>"` in an HTML file unless it's an actual literal tag. Use `"</scr" + "ipt>"` or `"<\/script>"` or anything else that isn't `"</script>"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
'<script>'+code.toString()+'<\/script>'
```

The browser closes the script element when it sees `'</script>'`, indicating the script close tag. Escaping the slash keeps the browser in text interpreting mode.

Or breaking it up as mentioned:

```
"<script>"+code.toString()+"<"+"/script>"
```